# ViewState is NULL in Page_Load but not postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, nullreferenceexception

I've got a weird problem with a NullReferenceException on a high traffic website my company hosts.  The exceptions are logged with full stack-traces but I am unable to reproduce it.

The exception occurs a couple of times a day, for different users, and it's a NullReferenceException thrown in the code block below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ...
        this.ViewState[StaticClass.StaticStringProperty] = StaticClass.StaticIntProperty; // this is the line the exception occurs on
        ...
    }
}
```

The only place I can figure that a NullReferenceException would be thrown is if `ViewState` is NULL, but I've never known that and can't find any reason why this would be the case in a Page_Load that isn't a postback.

`StaticStringProperty` and `StaticIntProperty` are both initialised, static properties of `StaticClass`.

`StaticStringProperty` is defined as:

```
public const string StaticStringProperty = "IdFromClient";
```

Does anyone know how this could happen, or any other reason why a NullReferenceException would be thrown on the above line?

**EDIT**

As requested, the full stack-trace for the error is as follows.  Line 54 is the line I've highlighted above.

```
at MyCompany.MyApplication.Appliance.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and  Settings\shellama\My Documents\MyApplication\Appliance.aspx.cs:line 54
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at MyCompany.MyApplication.PageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\shellama\My Documents\MyApplication\App_Code\PageBase.cs:line 58
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: What do you mean why you say both properties are initialised? Are their values set from another page/class in the application? Even though you don't think it's relavent, you should still provide the properties in question.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide the declaration of `StaticStringProperty` - it's a hard-coded string that never changes. `StaticIntProperty` is an int so will never be null.

Comment: @Andy - I see what you mean now. I'm as lost as you!

Comment: Hi Andy, so many times I though I knew in which line a null pointer exception was thrown, and it turned out I was in error. So you might want to post the whole code block to find in which other line it could have occurred.

Comment: @chiccodoro, thanks for the suggestion. We leave the PDBs in production and it pin-points this exact line in the stack-trace.

Comment: I see. This looks real weird... The only thing I could imagine is that using static classes and static fields makes problems. Maybe you want to report this issue to Microsoft?

Comment: Are you using the default ViewState provider?

Comment: @Bryan - Yes, I am. I've decided to store my required value in a hidden control instead of the ViewState to see if this helps.

Comment: Where you have this.ViewState[StaticClass.StaticStringProperty] = ..., have you tried without the static properties? this.ViewState["test"] = 123; and checked to see if it throws an exception? Would identify if the issue is the viewstate or the properties then.

Comment: Its possible that the line# given by the stack trace is incorrect. http://www.comanswer.com/question/wrong-line-number-on-stack-trace  Therefore, the full page_load is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say about it (I had a similar situation recently) is that `StaticClass.StaticStringProperty` is NULL. But then again, you must have paid attention to this. I can't think of something else.

Comment: Yeah that's the only other thing I could think of, but it's a hard-coded string.  I've edited my question to provide the declaration of `StaticStringProperty`. `StaticIntProperty` is an int so will never be null.

Comment: Perhaps you could give the stack trace to take a look.

Comment: I've posted the stack-trace.  I can't see anything particularly useful in there but feel free to take a look.